# Altering database structure on Smartface application upgrade

Tags: smartface.io

What is the best approach to alter an existing database on Smartface application upgrade?

New version of my app has slightly different database structure (new columns were added).

When upgraded happened GUI-desined datasets are new (with new columns) while existing database is old (without those columns).

Existing database contains user data meaning replacing it with an empty one is not an option.

The following code is not working (column is not added):

```
Data.execute("ALTER TABLE TableSettings ADD COLUMN NewColumn TEXT;");
Data.execute("UPDATE TableSettings SET NewColumn = 'test is fine';");
Data.DatasetSettings.refresh();
```

Pls share some ideas how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

During upgrade, if the structure of table is same and has keepDataOnUpdate flag true, data will be kept.

**Method1**
You may use new table to work with. Copy data from exiting to new one and delete records inside old one. Do not remove old table.

**Method2**
You may alter table as you do now. For future versions, add some checks to database to avoid re-adding of column by script. Use dynamic dataset to work with that table. Static datasets are tightly bound to table meta during publish; With static dataset you cannot use your new columns.

In future versions of Smartface (expected 4.5 or 4.6) database management will be given to users providing more control on what is on database and more control about update procedures.